# is it possible call batch script presented in the slave machine by using jenkins

Tags: shell, jenkins, batch-processing, jenkins-cli, jenkins-scriptler

I had installed my jenkins master in the linux.
slave in the windows environment.
I am trying to call the batch script presented in the slave(windows) machine.
But I am not able to do this.
If any one this please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

On the master job configuration, have you checked the **Restrict where this project can be run** checkbox and entered the slave name in the **Label Expression**?

To enter a Label expression, you first need to add the slave as a node on the master: *Manage Jenkins -> Manage Nodes -> New Node*

Some further info on configuring slaves can be found [here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Step+by+step+guide+to+set+up+master+and+slave+machines)